# condition within outer join?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

my simplified query looks like:

```
 SELECT p.product_Id,
       p.productName,
       s.LastSales_date
FROM products as p 
            LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (  SELECT product_id , 
           max(Sales_date) as LastSales_date  
          FROM Sales group by product_id) as s
on s.product_id=p.product_Id 
where  
  (s.LastSales_date is null or  -- is it right? 
  s.LastSales_date between '2012/01/01' and '2012/01/05')
```

the result:

```
ProductName       LastSalesDate  
   p_A             2012/01/01
   p_C             2012/01/01
   p_E             2012/01/02
```

but there is on row missed, that row which without sales_date, so, how to get a result like:

```
ProductName       LastSalesDate  
   p_A             2012/01/01
   p_b             <null>
   p_C             2012/01/01
   p_E             2012/01/02
```

my problem the rows with  (null) are not appear
I appreciate any try :-)

Comment: What is wrong with your current query?, what results do you get?, what **data** is on your tables?

Comment: What datatype is the `Sales_date` column?

Comment: i need to show the null values... to let the user know this product has no sales.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When working with outer join it is important to remember to filter outer side data from join itself, otherwise one produces inner join in effect.

```
SELECT p.product_Id,
       p.productName,
       s.LastSales_date
FROM products as p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (
   SELECT product_id , 
          max(Sales_date) as LastSales_date  
     FROM Sales 
    group by product_id
 ) as s
on s.product_id = p.product_Id 
-- Filter s here
and s.LastSales_date between '2012/01/01' and '2012/01/05'
```

In this instance you might filter aggregate itself, using HAVING:

```
SELECT p.product_Id,
       p.productName,
       s.LastSales_date
FROM products as p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
 (
   SELECT product_id , 
          max(Sales_date) as LastSales_date  
     FROM Sales 
    group by product_id
-- Filter max(Sales_date) here
   having max(Sales_date) between '2012/01/01' and '2012/01/05'
 ) as s
on s.product_id = p.product_Id
```

Comment: result should contains the null if there is no sales data for a product.

Comment: @salahaldin so it will. Did you try?

Comment: Great thanks,I modified my query and it work.. also your answer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd expect the result that you've mentioned, but if you're finding that isn't working, I'd recommend using COALESCE.

Perhaps...

```
SELECT
p.product_Id
, p.productName
, COALESCE(s.LastSales_date,'')
FROM
products p 
LEFT OUTER JOIN
    (SELECT
        product_id
        , MAX(Sales_date) AS LastSales_date  
    FROM
        Sales
    GROUP BY
        product_id
    )  s on s.product_id = p.product_Id 
WHERE  
COALESCE(s.LastSales_date,'')  = ''
OR
COALESCE(s.LastSales_date,'') BETWEEN  '2012/01/01' and '2012/01/05'
```